# How to filter data as long as a group contains certain values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
3       | B    |
3       | C    |
4       | D    |
4       | C    |
```

I want to return VisitID rows as long as that VisitID had a occurrence of item A OR B. How do I go about? Expected Result:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
3       | B    |
3       | C    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can select groups where `any` `Item` has either `'A'` or `'B'`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(VisitID) %>% filter(any(Item %in% c('A', 'B')))

#  VisitID Item 
#    <int> <fct>
#1       1 A    
#2       1 B    
#3       1 C    
#4       1 D    
#5       2 A    
#6       2 D    
#7       2 B    
#8       3 B    
#9       3 C
```

Or in base R :

```
subset(df, ave(Item %in% c('A', 'B'), VisitID, FUN = any))
```

and in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(Item %in% c('A', 'B'))], VisitID]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(VisitID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L), Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), 
row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It seems you get also Items with "C" and "D" in your `dplyr` approach. Did you mean `filter( Item %in% c('A', 'B') )` ? You don't want in fact to use `any` here since it returns TRUE for all (from the help "Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?").

Comment: @cbo It is inline with OP's expected output. If I have understood them correctly. Select groups if either "A" or "B" is in group.

Comment: I also think it's useful to use dplyr::filter rather than filter, as 'filter' is a function within the stats package in R, so it can clash and cause confusing error messages

Comment: @sahwahn after `library(dplyr)`, `filter` will be masked from `stat`. Using `::` might look redundant.

Comment: perhaps i have some different settings in my .Rprofile about masking different libraries, but using library(dplyr) and then calling filter still returns the filter from stats package.

Comment: @RonakShah my bad, I read too fast ^^'  `any` is required here indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In base R, I would do:

```
df <- data.frame(VisitID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                 Item = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "B", "B", "C", "D", "C"))

do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$VisitID), function(x) if(any(x[,2] %in% c("A", "B"))) x else NULL))

# VisitID Item
# 1.1       1    A
# 1.2       1    B
# 1.3       1    C
# 1.4       1    D
# 2.5       2    A
# 2.6       2    D
# 2.7       2    B
# 3.8       3    B
# 3.9       3    C
```

Answer (score 2):

Another filtering condition without grouping the data:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(VisitID %in% VisitID[Item %in% c('A', 'B')])

#   VisitID Item
# 1       1    A
# 2       1    B
# 3       1    C
# 4       1    D
# 5       2    A
# 6       2    D
# 7       2    B
# 8       3    B
# 9       3    C
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base` solution :.

```r
groups <- rowsum(x = as.numeric( df$Item %in% c("A", "B") ), group = df$VisitID)
df[df$VisitID %in% rownames(groups)[groups > 0] , ]
```